# Is "on the side of" right here?

Tags: meaning, writing-style

> China’ government faces a lot  of challenges in global politics and
>   domestic politics. On the side of global politics, it is criticized
>   for its lack of moral courage to take side in conflicts. On the side
>   of domestic politics, the people are not contended with only living as
>   a happy pig, they start to struggle for political freedom. 
>   (self-made)

I only know the use of “on the side of” in expressions like “to err on the side of…”, not sure whether “on the side of “ is good  here. Is there any another alternative? For example, “in the respect of”.

Comment: There are too many "sides" in your example. I think maybe you can use "on the one hand, on the other". And you should say "take _sides_ in conflicts".

Comment: Also, “simply […] living as a happy pig” sounds quite odd here to me. In fact, I don’t quite know how to interpret it. The Chinese have not generally been seen as being ‘happy as a pig (in mud)’ (which is an established idiom, unlike ‘living as a happy pig’, which isn’t) to begin with, so the sentence does not make much sense.

Comment: I get this notion from Plato's Republic, where Glaucon says that the lowest polis is that of pigs, who are happy and satisfied only if they are well-clad, well-fed.

Comment: ...and 'Better Socrates discontented than a pig contented' is a well-known summary of that passage in the Republic.  I picked up the reference before I read the comments, though the author is assuming a certain amount of erudition.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is perfectly valid in the context, but it is not, in my view, well used in this instance. Besides you have employed it twice in successive sentences, which is not a feature of good writing.

There are two spelling mistakes in the piece. In the second line 'side' should be in the plural -sides. And contented is spelled with a t not a d.

Had I been writing the piece I would have said something like:

'China's government faces a lot of challenges, both in global and domestic politics. In global matters, it is criticised for its lack of moral courage to take sides in conflicts. Domestically , the people are no longer contented simply with living as a happy pig, a struggle has begun for political freedom.'

I hope that has not changed your meaning at all. I don't think it has. But let me know!

Comment: You got me right. Of course, your sentence is much better. May I add this: the repetition of one word or phrase in sucessive sentences is not good, if you can find a better way to express your meaning. Maybe in this case, "on the side of" has to be used. China's economic growth and its rising up have many implications both for economics and sociology. On the side of economics, we are left with a big question: how can economy flourish in a non-free-market; on the side of sociology...

Comment: @user51369 It is clear what you mean, and you deserve credit for being able to express yourself in English. I certainly couldn't do it in Chinese! But it is apparent that what you have said are not the words of a native English speaker. Based on my own experience with French, it will take a lifetime to achieve that. I would say 'China's economic growth and its consequent rise in international importance have implications both economic and social. Economically, a big question remains. How can the economy continue to flourish without free markets? Sociologically speaking....'

Comment: Although I am not capable of writing what you just have written, I certainly recognize that you are right again. But maybe my failure to persuade you is just because of the fact that my example is not sophisticated enough. I will try again. China's Taoism is incompatible with many views in modern metaphysics and moral philosophy. On the side of metaphysics, it is clear that Taosim presupposes the existence of a divine being, which is rejected by togay's metaphysicians.On the side of...
Sometimes, in scholarly discussion ,it is hard to find a natural way to express your ideas.

Comment: I am not clear about what you are hoping I will do. It seems you are trying to persuade me that the words 'on the side of...' must be used. It is correct in English, but a little cumbersome. There are more economical ways of saying it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am a little bit obstinate and impolite. Sorry for that! But I hope you forgive me, because, as a foreign learner, it is impossible to find a natural way to learn English. You have to thoroughly explored doubts which are highly entangled with and informed by the habits of your own language.

Comment: @user51369 Well the second part of the last sentence 'which are highly entangled with and informed by the habits of your own language', is wonderfully expressive English. It will be a painstaking journey for you but I feel sure you will achieve excellent English at the rate you are going.

Comment: @user51369 It occurs to me that what you are seeking is the expression  'On the one hand'......'on the other hand'. This is an idiom in regular use in English. You can say, for example 'On the one hand China's Taoism is incompatible with modern metaphysics, on the other (hand) it does provide a basis for a belief system compatible with modernisation.' (If that is what you want to say - the idea is only there as an example of how to use English!)